# Is it possible to add line break for uilabel if it is assigned by webview string?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am getting the string from web view and display it as `UILabel`. I use the following code:

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSAttributedString* convertedString =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithData: [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
 options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
 documentAttributes: nil
 error: &err];
```

In the above code, `urlString` is my html code. Now, when I load this, if the line is too big, it got hidden out of the frame. So is it possible to display that in next line?

Comment: `[yourLabel setNumberOfLines:0];`? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No. it works, when I directly set the string. In the above condition, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
```

The  `lineBreakMode` has several different options. You can view all the options here - [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode)

After that you can apply `[yourLabel sizeToFit];
    yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;` (or NO).